# how to write a tigger in sql server to send a push notification (GCM) to android phone?

Tags: android, sql-server, triggers, google-cloud-messaging

i have applied the demo code of GCM for server side on appache server and for client side on android device and it is working great; but i need to activate this service in my application as follows:
i have a database on SqlServer and need to automatically send a push notification to android phone whenever some certain data gets modified, i think i should use an after update and after insert trigger to do this, but i don't know how to do it.
any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this "certain data" only in one table or multiple?

Answer (score 1):

You should not do it from a trigger. Adding the latency of a GCM push to each table update will quickly bring the performance to unbearable lows. You have to decouple the trigger from the GCM call, and the best way to achieve it is via a queue.

- You can [use a table as a queue](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) and have an external process monitor the queue and handle the GCM call.
- You can use [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) and deliver the GCM call from an [internal activated procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or from an external process that monitors the queue
- You can use [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and monitor an NT queue from an external process.

My recommendation would be to go with first option as is the simplest and has the inherent robustness of simplicity. Read the linked article to understand what is required to use tables as queues, and do not cut corners.

All options still rely on a trigger to enqueue the notification, but it will be a local enqueue, not a GCM call.

I'm sure someone will think of the naive solution of invoking GCM from the trigger itself using SQLCLR: don't do it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i am not very familiar with this topic, can you please provide me with some more explanation or a tutorial that will help me implement the code.